# Plutus-starter - cannot start contract instance

Tags: plutus, wallet, pab, plutus-starter

I am following the link below. I've successfully built the docker image (literally had to upgrade to 32 GB of RAM, it used 15 GB at peak RAM usage during cabal build). I have the PAB server running successfully and was able to create the two wallets as defined in the tutorial.

When I try to run **Section 2: Start the instances**:

> curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \   --request POST \
> --data '{"caID": "GameContract", "caWallet":{"getWalletId": '$WALLET_ID_1'}}' \   http://localhost:9080/api/contract/activate | jq

I get the error code:

> parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6

I am new to using jq - I cannot figure out which tag corresponds to "column 6". Can anyone help me out? Am I supposed to change some ' to "? Or do I need to replace $WALLET_ID_1 with the wallet pub key hash? I've tried both with no success.

https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

My Plutus build has an old version of the Wallet package (see https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/3844/3951). I could get the contract instance ID by running:

> curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ --request POST 
> --data '{"caID": "GameContract", "caWallet":{"getWallet": 1}}' \ http://localhost:9080/api/contract/activate | jq